# 証券コードからEDINETコードへの変換

Tags: edinet

[EDINET](http://disclosure.edinet-fsa.go.jp/) から上場会社の決算データ(XBRL)を取得するプログラムを作成しようとしています。その際、EDINET コードではなく証券コードで指定したいので、証券コードから EDINET コードを自動的に求めたいと思います。

例: 7203→E02144 (トヨタ自動車)

将来的に上場する会社も対応したいので、プログラム内部に変換表を持つのではなくて、できれば公開されているリソースから取得したいと思っています。

公開されている情報や、参考となる情報があれば教えてください。

なお、プログラムは Linux上の Ruby で作成する予定ですが。情報源がライブラリ等の場合、OS 言語はなんでも OK です。

Answer (score 3):

TDnetの決算短信の財務諸表をみるといいらしいです。http://d.hatena.ne.jp/xbrl/20090621/1245573739

http://www.tse.or.jp/rules/td/xbrl/data/

実装例がありますね。これを参考にすればいいかと
http://qiita.com/shima_x/items/c1955743cb5784505ac9